# Access/Edit pixel values of a jpeg image in python

Tags: python, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I'm involved in a image processing project and I use python. I'm new to python, so please bear my lack of knowledge. I want to read a `jpeg` image, split it into `r,g,b`. Then I have to change add a value to each pixel `r,g,b` separately. Finally, I have to merge three of them to create a new image and save it.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("/home/pi/desktop/codes/lena.jpg")
im.show()

r,g,b =im.split()
```

Are `r,g,b` matrices containing pixel values? Can I change the values of the pixels directly? And can some one please tell me how to access each pixel?

Comment: You should explicitly mention PIL module because this is not part of standard Python distribution. If your r,g,b are all list objects then you can use `r[]`, `g[]`, `b[]` to access the pixel values, just like any other python list operation. you put the indices inside `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you [split](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.split) the image into individual bands.

Then maniplulate each pixels as you want using [point](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.point).

Then merge three bands using [merge](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.merge).

The `split` method returns a tuple

> **Image.split()**
>   Split this image into individual bands. This method returns a tuple of
>   individual image bands from an image. For example, splitting an “RGB”
>   image creates three new images each containing a copy of one of the
>   original bands (red, green, blue).

Comment: Thanx alot for the response. Does this split function returns the individual band as a matrix? And can you please tell me how to use the "point". If you can provide me an example code that will be very helpful.